# repetitions being Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Let $R(n)$ be the repetition of $n$, e.g. $R(1)=11$, $R(120)=120120$ etc.

$R(5)=55$ is a Fibonacci number, the only one I found.

Is $55$ really the only repetition in Fibonacci sequence?

If not, is the set of all $n$ such that $R(n)$ is a Fibonacci number, finite or not?

// own question, I don't know neither the solution not the answer...

Comment: The definition of your formula, then, would be $R(x)=x(10^{\left \lfloor log_{10}(x) \right \rfloor + 1}+1)$, which you can [play around on Wolfram|Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/mkt7mtu). $Fibonacci(n)=\left [ \frac{(\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5}))^{n}}{\sqrt{5}} \right ]$. (See [Generating Fibonacci Numbers](http://datagenetics.com/blog/october22015/index.html) and [Wolfram|Alpha](http://tinyurl.com/mk3puxr)) The trick, then, would be to find out an $n$ and an $x$ that yield a common output.

Comment: $R(n)$ will be divisible by the relevant one of $101,1001,10001,\dots$ I expect we will find that the [Fibonacci entry point](https://oeis.org/A001177) for each of these will be far too high for a repetition to exist. For example, $F_{50}=12586269025$ is the first Fibonacci number after $0$ to be divisible by $101$. I'm not sure how to prove this. See also [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).